# Images Tile on Google map to display on screen with specific position

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing android application with custom google map using TileProvider and I have set the image on that also and its move look like normanl google map.

I am plotting images tiles bases from assets folder.

I want to implement is like if I have provide specific location or tile it should be display on screen from tile images.

Thanks in advance.